# java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, cassandra

I have following java code to connect with cassandra. it is giving  java.lang.NumberFormatException

any idea?

```
package com.retail;

import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.*;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.*;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.*;

import java.lang.*;

public class ShowKeyspaces {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String host = System.getenv("localhost");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("9160"));

    TSocket socket = new TSocket(host,port);
    TTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(socket);

    TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
    transport.open();

    Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);

    System.out.println("Version: "+client.describe_version());
    System.out.println("cluster name : "+client.describe_cluster_name());

    transport.close();  
    }

}
```

Error it is giving is:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.retail.ShowKeyspaces.main(ShowKeyspaces.java:14)**
```

Any idea how I should go about this???

Thanks!

Comment: Why `int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("9160"));`  and not just `int port = 9160;` ?

Comment: because System.getenv only takes string parameter and while storing it in port it should a integer.

Comment: Its also why you are getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, wrap it around in a try catch to verify. Using `system.getenv` in this manner doesn't really make sense, maybe you want `System.getenv("port")`?

Comment: If you have an exception,  looking at and proving the stacktrace are the most important things to do.

Comment: I'm seeing `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""5984""` when trying to run a testng test where I set the `COUCHDB_PORT` env var with value `5984` and read it as `int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("COUCHDB_PORT"));` Not sure how the additional "" is added to the value 5984

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` because of this line:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("9160"));
```

I think you haven't set **9160** as a system property and `System.getenv("9160")` is returning an empty string, aka "". So either [set *9160* as an environment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) variable or simply:

```
int port = 9160;
```

Comment: The line "System.getenv("localhost");" contains a quite similar error. I'd bet that "localhost" should be the value of some environment variable and not the variablename.

Comment: @mschenk74 I agree with you, same with `System.getenv("9160")`.